# Convergence of Series for tangent (only convergence or divergence)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^2 \ \ $$

My first guess is to write the series as integral. And use the substitution for u=1/n. That changes my upper and lower bounded limits to - lower = 1/17 and upper to 0. In that case switch the limits and put a negative sign. I fail to understand what is really going on after that.

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$ ($17$ is more than big enough) you have $ \frac1n \lt \tan \frac1n \lt \frac2n$ so the question becomes equivalent to whether $\displaystyle \sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^2$ converges.

Comment: yes it does! but what series is that? is that the geometric series?

Comment: Consider $\displaystyle \int_{16}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx$

Comment: what is the relationship between the integral and the sum? they are not the same are they?

Comment: A sum is an integral of a bar-chart like function.  Can you compare the area of the bar-chart like function to the area of a continuous function whose integral you can compute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that $\tan(x)$ is equivalent to $x$ when $x$ goes to $0$. Then the general term of your serie is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then you can conclude that your serie is convergent by the comparison theorem, as $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.